# Set button disabled on call time

Tags: android

I have application, that can dial number via click Call button. Here code of button `onClickListener`.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + obj.getPhoneNumber()));
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + obj.getPhoneNumber()));
                    callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(callIntent);
```

How I can disable this button when phone call start, and enable when phone call end? My problem is that user can click button twice while dialer starting, and dialer run in background (not on top of task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using and registering a `PhoneStateListener` (see [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)) in your `Activity` class.

The docs state this class is the following:

> A listener class for monitoring changes in specific telephony states on the device, including service state, signal strength, message waiting indicator (voicemail), and others.

It can be easily registered in your `Activity` or `Fragment` by using an inner class such as this:

```
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myButton = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    TelephonyMgr.listen(new MyListener(),
    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

public void enableButton(){
   myButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public void disableButton(){
   myButton.setEnabled(false);
}

class MyListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            // CALL_STATE_IDLE
            enableButton();
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            disableButton();
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // CALL_STATE_RINGING
            disableButton();
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

This will require the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

The list of call states the device is defined in `TelephonyManager` - [see docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Add this line after your

```
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: What about enable button, when phone call end?

Comment: Add phoneStateLister and then reenable it when call finished. U need to write your own custom Class for this.